# Hats, hats, hats, hats, lovely hats, wonderful hats

Tags: discussion, winterbash

According to this [post on meta.math](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17368/97480), there will be hats again this year.  This time, it will be for all SE sites that don't opt out.  There's an [informal poll on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18671110#18671110) about having hats again this year.

(I want hats. Yay! hats.)

Comment: Note that similar to last year, [Gilles started an informal poll in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18671110#18671110). As long as nobody objects there or, now, here, we're going to participate again.

Comment: Ah -- I don't follow chat so I'd not seen that.

Comment: (Maybe, as the active user that you are, you should? :))

Comment: Perhaps, but that might lead to even more procrastination from the real world.

Comment: What can I say... maybe we can occasionally remind each other to get back to work? :D (Seriously, though: the chat is not overly busy but some (meta) discussions start and take form there. Would be great to have you -- and others interested! -- there for your input.)

Comment: bring it on *<:)