# Will we have winter hats this year?

Tags: discussion, winterbash

Probably a duplicate of [Hats, hats, hats, hats, lovely hats, wonderful hats](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/958/hats-hats-hats-hats-lovely-hats-wonderful-hats)

This year I missed any discussion about winter hats. Is this folklore discontinued?

**Late Edit.** As per 2023 the folklore is indeed discontinued. Well, not discontinued, but [being sunsetted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392846/630218). Horrible word.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, we will have hats. [Starting in <s>521,031</s> <s>521,030</s> <s>521,029</s> … seconds](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/).

We (the moderators) decided that since there had been overwhelming support the previous years, we'd opt in again this year (or rather, we wouldn't opt out — sites opt in by default).

Comment: Great. Love the hats!